# TextInput style Props type react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to pass style as props to my custom `TextInput` component.I found [this](https://medium.com/@zvona/stylesheets-in-react-native-with-typescript-revisited-6b4ba0a899d2) snippet to type button and label style in props :

```
import {  
  StyleProp,
  Text,
  TextStyle,
  View,
  ViewStyle
} from 'react-native';

interface IProps {
 label: string;
  buttonStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  labelStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
}
// rest
```

but I did not find anything for `TextInput` nor any documentation about `StyleProp`
So what is the proper way to pass style to TextInput?

Comment: Can you add some code of your custom TextInput component?

Comment: @DevAttendant I found the answer

Answer (score 2):

I was checking `TextInputProps` interface and I found `TextStyle` is also used for `TextInput` :

```
style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
```

so it can be used in these ways :

```
import {StyleSheet, TextInput, TextInputProps , StyleProp , 
TextStyle } from 'react-native';

type Props = {
style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>,
// or 
style?: Pick<TextInputProps, "style">

};

const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({style: propStyles}) =>
    <TextInput
      style={ [styles.input, propStyles] }
    />


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {...}, 
});
```